# Creating a simple like counter using PHP and AJAX

Tags: php, sql, ajax, codeigniter

I'm building a web application with CodeIgniter.

Posts on the site can be loved by users. I have developed the model that pulls in the total number of loves, but I would like to make this update using AJAX whenever a new love is added.

Total love counts are displayed with the following code:

```
<p><a href="#" id="lovecounter"><?php if ($post->love) { echo $post->love; } else { echo 0; } ?></a></p>
```

The database table that holds the love data is called "post_rating" and is structured as follows:

- id
- post_id
- user_id
- rating

The "rating" column will be 0 when default or 1 for a love.

Where do I go from here?

Truth be told, I'm a total noob when it comes to Javascript and AJAX. I have absolutely no idea where to start, so any direction or ideas would be very much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Make an AJAX request (using jQuery, for example) to a controller, and have the controller echo the needed response; now AJAX would pick that response, and you can manipulate it as you please

Comment: Nice explanation. Thanks for breaking down the process, Damien!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery makes AJAX very easy.  I recently learned it myself.  Read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16751/Implementing-AJAX-in-your-Applications-How-Simple) and [this](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/05/insert-and-load-record-using-jquery-and.html) for good examples.

Comment: Thanks for the links, Jeff. I read the first one but it lost me at the JSP section. I'm going to watch a few AJAX/CodeIgniter videos in the morning.

Comment: Yeah, that second link is actually much more useful and applicable to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Create a php page on the server that accepts request that are triggered by the "love" button being pressed.  In this php page you can increment the counter and update the DB where this is stored.  Then when pages are rendered they can load this new count from the DB.  Using a design pattern like MVC makes this really easy as all your request can be routed to the correct content.  I use this very approach on www.phpblueprint.com to load each of the sliding pages dynamically from a server running PHPBlueprint.

On the client side just have the "love" button trigger an ajax event using an XMLHttpRequest or just use the jQuery libraries Ajax API (very, very simple and powerful).

**UPDATE**

Sorry just saw you are using CodeIgniter, this is a great MVC framework.  [This will help you with what you want to do.](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-8-ajax/)

Comment: Cheers, mate. I actually had that video saved on my computer believe it or not. I downloaded the entire series! I'll watch it again tomorrow and see if I can make sense of it all.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think that the "rating" column it's not very useful, you only have to count the number of rows that a post have searching by "post_id" and you'll have the number of "loves" or "likes" people have voted.

Then, about javascript and ajax, I also suggest using JQUERY, it makes very easy working with AND now Codeigniter comes with a javascript library that has jquery http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/javascript.html

In your case, in my web, in the likes we have used this method: calling a controller function with all the data via post or uri or what you want, and answering with an echo of json like:

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
$this->output->set_content_type('application/json')
->set_output(json_encode(
     array('love' =>($this->loves_model->love_inserted() == TRUE)?'true':'false')
);
```

Then you only have to get the data via jquery and change the DOM with it.

Comment: The reason I've included the rating column is because I plan on adding "hate" functionality down the line. Hates will be represented by a -1. Does that make sense?

Comment: You can also count the hates, but if you have a lot of them it will consume a lot.